# How to use a shorthand ternary operator php in sql query ?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query which update data, include image. 
But in edit.php (in existing item), an image is allready exist.

I tried to add shorthand operator, but something is going wrong and return an errror. Below is my code. Maybe i have an error with my quotes ? Please help !

```
 q("
                    UPDATE `goods` SET
                    `title`             = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title']) . "',
                    `cat`               = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cat']) . "',
                    `description`       = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']) . "',
                    `img` = '" . $_FILES['file'] ?: mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $obj->name);."',
                    `price`             = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['price']) . "'
                    WHERE `id` = " . (int)$_GET['key1'] . "
                ");
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in /var/..../edit.php on line 25

Comment: in general, Is this correct decision for current situation ? Using an ternary operator ?

Comment: ternary is good if consider default value also. what happend if `$_FILES['file']` not present

Comment: if $_FILES['file'] not present - query must be done without : `img` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $obj->name) ."'

Comment: Thank you !  i found a decision :" . ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 ? " `img` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $obj->name) . "'," : '') . "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change here, remove `;`

```
`img` = '" . $_FILES['file'] ?: mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $obj->name)."',
```

Comment: when i try to update data without upload image - nothing happens. I mean - looks like query breaks. When upload an image - see that : Array to string conversion in /var/../edit.php on line 27

Comment: what do you mean by `nothing happens` ?

Comment: just print what query you are getting echo '" UPDATE `goods` SET .............................. WHERE `id` = " . (int)$_GET['key1'] ' ?

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/school-php.com/domains/parabellum/public_html/modules/admin/goods/edit.php on line 26
UPDATE `goods` SET `title` = '123123123', `cat` = 'budget', `description` = '123123', `img` = 'Array

Comment: Use `$_FILES['file']['name']` or from which you get file name

Comment: Thank`s a lot !  i understood how to made it.

Comment: " . ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 ? " `img` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $obj->name) . "'," : '') . "